# long text inside ion-input field can not be scrolled horizontal [Ionic 2] [iOS]

Tags: ios, input, ionic2

Does anyone have faced issue like this before? The issue is when I have longer text inside ion-input field I can't scroll through it horizontal. This issue is ios only related. It works fine on Android though.

```
<ion-item>
 <ion-input> </ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

[image: i can not scroll through the text in ion input horizontally]

Comment: any updates on this?